# Auto Format HTML/PHP With Line Breaks and Tabs

Tags: php, html

I've run into a problem. Someone on our team edited a HTML/PHP file, and the entire contents of the file ended up on a single line. All line breaks and tabs were completely removed from the file. Its a very large file, so trying to edit it manually would take forever.

Does anyone know of a tool I can use to re-format the code?

Comment: Why don't you roll back to an earlier revision? You *are* using a version control system, right? ;o)

Comment: There are lots - what OS do you have access to? If you write PHP that means you've got code editors - most of which can do this for you. What code editors do you use?

Comment: @symcbean I use Notepad++, and didn't find any formatting options.

Comment: it doesn't do it out of the box - but there are several plugins for notepad++ to implement this - try goolge

Comment: Edit question instead of marking it as off-topic.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the [NetBeans IDE](http://netbeans.org/), for the development purpose. Then open the file in that IDE and press these keys at the same time - <kbd>Alt</kbd> +
 <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

The file will get formatted nicely, and also will show you if there are any errors in that file.

Comment: This is wrong answer, as for Netbeans 8.0.2 auto formatting doesn't work for long one-liners.

Comment: What about html and php together in code. I tried many online "purifiers" and none of them does the job without error. if it does, then it mess something else up. What is best tool to use for auto formating html and php code in one file?

Answer (score 13):

You could use `DOMDocument` to tidy the HTML.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->formatOutput = TRUE;

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: `$DOMDocument->saveHTML()` will add HTML 4 headers to your markup. It's end of 2016

Comment: @hosein this was answered 2011. Feel free to update it.

Answer (score 4):

(First link removed per comment below.)

http://www.phpformatter.com/ is an option.

Comment: Warning:  http://www.decodephp.com/codecleaner/ expired and is now owned by spammers and malware-pushers.  While it is fairly obviously not a codecleaner anymore, it is also random where it sends you, so I felt this warning merited.

Comment: @GDom updated to remove that link, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [tidy](http://infohound.net/tidy/) (html only) or [codecleaner](http://www.decodephp.com/codecleaner/)

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio. Open the HTML file then press ctrl k then ctrl d (or use the edit menu).

Answer (score 1):

In Aptana or Zend Studio or Eclipse PHP, you can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to auto format your code. Remember to fix all syntax errors before.