# Format html code with PHP

Tags: php, html, formatting, format, tidy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP “pretty print” HTML (not Tidy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768215/php-pretty-print-html-not-tidy)

Lets say I have php var contains this string :

```
 <html><head><title>Page title</title></head><body><div>content here</div></body></html>
```

How I can to format this html code with php ?
When I say format I mean to add line breaks and add tabs to this code to be like :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        content here
    </body>
</html>
```

I know there is tidy extension to php , but I need an alternative solution for that.

Thanks.

Comment: "but I need an alternative solution" - because of?

Comment: you can get an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516318/auto-format-html-php-with-line-breaks-and-tabs

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891416/an-alternative-to-php-tidy

Comment: What is the difference between the contents of the `<body/>` tag and that of the `<title/>` tag? Let aside a script, how can a person know why the former is stuck inside the tags whereas the latter is located in a separate line and tabbed at first place? Also, if you're sure it's gonna be strict html then I would suggest you to parse it as XML instead.