# How can I read the nth line of a web page's HTML, using PHP?

Tags: php, line, file-get-contents

I've seen this question for files, but for some reason they won't ever work with a web page.

I'm trying to use `file_get_contents` to get the contents of a web page (don't care much about speed, hence I'm not using cURL), and then I want to print a specific line.

Can you please give me the simplest possible way of doing this, as I'm creating an API which fetches specific lines from multiple web pages.

Alternatively, is there a way I can search for and print a line that contains a certain string? For example, a line that starts with "Foo" (if there's only one line containing that).

Answer (score 4):

```
function readStrLine($str, $n) {
    $lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $str);
    return $lines[$n-1];
}

$file = file_get_contents('http://google.pl');

echo readStrLine($file, 10);
```

you can explode string by new line, then you got array of lines which start with index 0 (it's first line)

**EDIT**
alternative way with tidy html

```
function readHtmlLine($html, $n) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    $dom->formatOutput = true;
    $lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $dom->saveHTML());
    return $lines[$n-1];
}

$file = file_get_contents('http://google.pl');

echo readHtmlLine($file, 10);
```

Comment: I did that, but it doesn't work unless the 10 is a 1, and then it just prints the whole page, not a specific line. How would I go about printing, say, line 60, or 70 etc.?

Comment: it may not work, if page doesn't have any new line sign in response, but in this case you can't know lines unless you format html like e.g. chrome does it

Comment: if you want to format html, here's example how to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6516335/2962442

Comment: I don't know what exactly you want to do, but there're plenty of ways to get data from html contents, e.g. xpath, it quite good way to select data

Answer (score 1):

> How can I read a specific line of a WEB PAGE? [PHP]
>
> Can you please give me the simplest possible way of doing this, as I'm creating an api which fetches specific lines from multiple web pages.
>
> Alternatively, is there a way I can search for and print a line that contains a certain string?

Sample html file:

`file.html`

```
<html>
<head><title>File</title></head>
<body>
    <p>Nancy is my name</p>
    <p>James is my name</p>
    <p>Foo is my name</p>
    <p>Bob is my name</p>
</body>
</html>
```

simple php function:

```
function checkFile( $file, $keyword ) {

    // open file for reading
    $handle = @fopen( $file, 'r' );

    // check to make sure handle is valid
    if( $handle ) {

        // traverse file line by line
        while( ($line = fgets($handle)) !== false ) {

            // search for specific keyword no matter what case is used i.e. foo or Foo
            if( stripos($line, $keyword) === false ) {
                // string not found, continue with next iteration
                continue;
            } else {

                // keyword was found

                // close file
                fclose($handle);

                // return line
                return $line;
            }
        }
    }
}

$result = checkFile( 'file.html', 'foo' );

echo $result;
```

Outputs: `<p>Foo is my name</p>`

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'https://www..';

$content = file_get_contents($url);

if($content){

    $start = strpos($content, '<span>');// $start is the first word where you want to begin read code

    $end = strpos($content,'</span>',$start );// $end is the last word where you want to stop read code

    $result = substr($content,$start,$end - $start);// $result is the code you have read and you want to display
   
} else {
    $error = 'no data found';
}
```

Comment: You should put all your code enclosed within "```" ( 3 backticks ) so your code all get formatted. Also, by nth line do you mean in the source code of html or do you mean visually?

Comment: I mean in the source code of the webpage (so html), sorry for my confusing english and thanks for the tip! :D